# How to update multiple nested objects in Redux

Tags: arrays, object, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

Given the following Array of objects how would one update all of the qty's in each of the nested "locationData" Arrays Objects? By all, I mean not just all in the Object, but all in all Objects. The base object is say an Item and the locationData is locations the items are in.

What I am doing is displaying all Items with the locations to the user and the user can then click different buttons to distribute the un-allocated Quantity to the locations, which will update all of the objects with the chosen distribution.

1. Would I loop through the data in the React component and do a dispatch for each Item with a new locationData Array, replacing the old one?
2. Would I loop through the Items in the Actions and then call the Reducer with an entirely new Array of items with the new locationData?

I can do it with or without ImmutableJs, but I am not sure the best way to do this.

```
[
{   
    "isSelected":false,
    "itemid":"2557",
    "name":"Accessories : Awesome Cable",
    "quantity":6000,"quantityByCase":600,
    "locationData":[
        {"id":"5","name":"QA Location","enabled":true,"percentage":"200","shipcarrier":"","shipmethod":"","qty":0},
        {"id":"7","name":"Single Bin Location","enabled":true,"percentage":"50","shipcarrier":"","shipmethod":"","qty":0},
        {"id":"1","name":"Warehouse - East Coast","enabled":true,"percentage":"","shipcarrier":"1","shipmethod":"92","qty":0}
    ],
    "unAllocatedQuantityByCase":600
},
{
    "isSelected":false,
    "itemid":"40",
    "name":"Accessories : Crusher Game Pad",
    "quantity":50,"quantityByCase":50,
    "locationData":[
        {"id":"5","name":"QA Location","enabled":true,"percentage":"200","shipcarrier":"","shipmethod":"","qty":0},
        {"id":"7","name":"Single Bin Location","enabled":true,"percentage":"50","shipcarrier":"","shipmethod":"","qty":0},
        {"id":"1","name":"Warehouse - East Coast","enabled":true,"percentage":"","shipcarrier":"1","shipmethod":"92","qty":0}
    ],
    "unAllocatedQuantityByCase":50}]
```

Currently, I am doing the the calculations in my reducer EVEN_DISTRIB, but this does not feel right. What I am doing is taking the entire state and mapping it to the items variable. items.isSelected is hard coded to true at the moment for testing. I then do an even distribution of the 'unAllocatedQuantityByCase' for each item and then lastly return all of the items and the new state for this reducer. There will also be weighted and like item distributions later, but wanted to get the even distribution right before proceeding further.

```
export default function (state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
   case types.PO_RECEIVED:
     return state.concat(action.payload);

   case types.EVEN_DISTRIB: {
    let items = state.map(item => {
      item.isSelected = true;
      if (item.isSelected) {
        let quantity = item.unAllocatedQuantityByCase;
        let updateLocations = item.locationData.filter(location => location.enabled);
        let remainder = quantity % updateLocations.length;
        let divideqty = (quantity - remainder) / updateLocations.length;

        let loc = updateLocations.map(location => {
          var tempQty = divideqty;
          if (remainder >= 1) {
            tempQty++;
            remainder--;
          } else if (remainder > 0) {
            tempQty += remainder;
            remainder = 0;
          }
          location.qty = tempQty;
          return location
        });
        item.locationData = loc;
      }
      return item;
    });

    return items;
  }

  default:
    return state;
}}
```

Should these types of calculations be done in the reducer? or should I do them in the component and then call the action with this as the payload? or is there a better way to do this... Normalizing the data structure and then just updating all of the locations. I guess my question is where do these types of calculations take place in a React/Redux app?

Answer (score 0):

1. Actions: **are functions that just return an action object. no logic in actions.**
2. Would I loop through the data in the React component and do a dispatch for each Item with a new locationData Array, replacing the old one?: ***this just causes unnecessary re-renders cause the state will change each time you dispatch.***
3. show some code
   make your question clear so others can learn from it. and please show some code of what you are trying to do or be clear and to the point in your explanation.
   looking forward to helping you.

Answer (score 0):

First, the general suggested approach for organizing nested or relational data in a Redux store is to normalize it, much like tables in a database.  That makes your state flatter and easier to manage.  See [Redux FAQ](https://redux.js.org/faq#organizing-state-nested-data) and [Querying a Redux Store](https://medium.com/@adamrackis/querying-a-redux-store-37db8c7f3b0f) for more information on that concept.

Second, while it's up to you to decide how exactly you want to split your update logic, generally that work should be done in action creators or reducers, but *not* in your components. [Redux FAQ](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#structure-business-logic)  gives some suggestions on how to think about splitting that logic.  Some people will do all the work in their action creators and leave their reducers to simply merge the action contents into the store, others will have the action creator just dispatch and let the reducer do all the work.  I personally am somewhere in the middle-ish - I try to put sufficient info into the action for the reducer to do the work, and am willing to let the action creator do needed prep calculations, but prefer to keep the contents of the action relatively minimal.

Third, your current reducer logic looks overly complicated.  At a minimum, I would suggest breaking it up into smaller, simpler, pure helper functions that are easier to think about.  Also, remember that with Redux you should update your data "immutably", ie, always make copies and modify the copies, never modify the original versions.  The line `location.qty = tempQty;` appears to be directly mutating some of the original data, and that will generally cause your React components to not update properly.  (The `item.selected = true` line does so as well, obviously.)